# The value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'slug', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an error in Django that the value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'slug', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'. What do I need to change about my model to correct this?

Here is my admin.py file content:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'price', 'stock', 'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_editable = ['price', 'stock', 'available']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Here is the traceback error which I have no idea on how to solve I'm currently using the book Django by example learn the web framework and the error m getting is scarry

```
    ERRORS:
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E027) The value of 'prepopulated_fields' refers to 'slug', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E030) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["slug"][0]' refers to 'name', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'slug', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'price', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[3]' refers to 'stock', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'available', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[5]' refers to 'created', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[6]' refers to 'updated', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProductAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'available', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'created', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[2]' refers to 'updated', which does not refer to a Field.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to 'price', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[1]' refers to 'stock', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'.
<class 'shop.admin.ProductAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[2]' refers to 'available', which is not an attribute of 'shop.Product'.

System check identified 15 issues (0 silenced).
```

Here is my model file

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cateogry(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_list_by_category',
                       args=[self.slug])
class Product(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

Here is my view.py file content I think there is problem with objects.filter

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,'list.html',{'category': category,
                                       'categories': categories,'products': products})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two classes called Product in your models.py. The second one, which contains no fields, hides the first one, and it is the second one that is being used in the admin registration. Remove that second definition.

Comment: please I did not get your explanation

Comment: I'm sorry, what did you not get? You have two things called Product in models.py; delete the second one. (You only don't have two things called Category because you've misspelled it the second time.)

Comment: Or move the content from the second class to the first class.